# Can JavaFX be included on a Java SE project?

Tags: java, mysql, javafx, netbeans-7

I'm trying to create an Inventory project and have graphs on it. I'd like the graph to be created thru JavaFX and call it on a Java main class.  Is it possible to add a JavaFX class to a Java project?

I'm using netbeans btw.

Comment: what does it mean by words 'add to a Java project?' You wanna enhance your JavaSe project, so it will be desktop app?

Comment: its a desktop app and i wonder if its possible to include a JavaFX class on my project and call that on my JavaSE main class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaFX for Java 7 is different from JavaFX on Java 8. My advice would be to go for Java 8. Then maybe NetBeans 8 too. JavaFX and swing/awt have different event threads, though under java 8 there seems to be a better integration.

JavaFX and java swing are two separate worlds. One might embed JavaFX in swing. Though if you are at the start of a basically new project, then you might go for pure JavaFX.

JavaFX uses "properties", wrapped values that can have change listeners on them / data binding. This separation from components makes dealing with the Model-View-Controller paradigm a bit nicer / different. JavaFX components themselves are a slightly more difficult, as swing provides a full API full of setters. It can be hard to make a column right-aligned for the first time. Another thing that makes JavaFX harder, is the use of callbacks with generic types, lambda expressions. Giving the correct signature not always is straight-forward.

So embedding JavaFX in swing might be a good approach if there is much swing experience or existing code: see

- [Embediing Swing in JavaFX](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/8/embed_swing/jfxpub-embed_swing.htm) (the other way around) and
- [How to Use JavaFX in Your Swing Application](https://blogs.oracle.com/java/entry/how_to_use_javafx_in_your_swing_application)

If you mean, you have a NetBeans 7 Richt Client Application, then on the NetBeans.org there several small articles on JavaFX integration.